How can Kinesis Consumers react to new Shards in a stream?
I'm building a Consumer application using a Standard Iterator (not EFO). How can I tell if a new Shard has been added, or an old Shard removed? Do I essentially have to call DescribeStream constantly?
I'm using the AWS PHP SDK, if that matters, however I think this applies regardless of language.
